# Is it possible for a civilisation to create a substitute for sunlight?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, engineering

What is needed for this kind of technology and how much sense does it make to have this instead of just leaving the planet for a better one.

Comment: How big is this sun lamp?

Comment: If it's big enough, gravity will take care of containment for you. ;)

Comment: I don't understand what this plasma lamp has to do with a Dyson Sphere. A Dyson Sphere is a large device designed to collect all of a sun's sunlight for energy. This energy can be redirected into ordinary electric lamps.

Comment: @qelzin A dyson sphere would or could block out the sun so could substitute

Comment: @kingledion I will edit

Comment: Sunlight is basically a black-body spectrum at some temperature. If you heated up any substance to the temperature of the photosphere, you would get basically the same spectrum with minor differences having to do with emission spectra.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a flawed understanding of what provides sunlight. There's nothing special about solar plasma... any substance heated enough provides light... the color of light depends on the substance. _A fluorescent lightbulb contains plasma._

Comment: @SRM but as far as I know you can have a light bulb and a growing plant because of it, please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. But as I read it, you either need a sun -- i.e. it is a natural thing. Or you want an artificial source of heat/light that is much smaller than a sun. You can get that from any number of lightbulb sizes.

Comment: @Mendeleev: You can't keep a glowing plasma without some process like fusion to replace the energy - the light - that radiates away.  You can use light bulbs (or LEDs &c) to provide light for plants because the energy to produce the light comes from electricity.  And that energy ultimately comes either from the sun, or from nuclear power.  And blocking out the sun with a Dyson sphere would be an act of abysmal stupidity.

Comment: Plants grow under any kind of light.

Comment: A sulfur plasma lamp uses a small quartz sphere filled with sulfur to produce light that's pretty close to natural sunlight in terms of it's colour spectrum. The sulfur is 'plasmized' by a glorified microwave oven, several sulfur lamps currently illuminate the US National Air and Space Museum. Is that the kind of plasma sun lamp you were thinking of?

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions in a very little space, some of which have no relation. Consider separating

Comment: As written, the second part of the sentence in the body is unreadable.  Leaving what?  The answer to the title question is "Yes, we call that a [grow light](http://www.gardeners.com/how-to/gardening-under-lights/5080.html).  Marijuana growers use them to hide their plants inside."

Answer (score 4):

The device you're talking about is called a **fusion reactor**. A fusion reactor heats up hydrogen to turn it into plasma that fuses into helium just like in the sun. This hydrogen is too hot to be contained in any ordinary vessel so we use magnetic fields to contain it instead. The real world has fusion reactors but they're not quite good enough yet to be economical. A civilization with just a little bit better technology might be able to build one.

Comment: Does it provide sunlight?

Comment: A fusion reactor provides energy. That energy can be converted into all kinds of different forms including various wavelengths of light. By combining these different wavelengths of light you can create something indistinguishable from sunlight.

Comment: If it's fusing the same elements as the local star, then yes. Keep in mind this is a pretty intense process so the "lamp" would have to be constantly fed with matter for the reaction, and the "waste" elements would need to be removed.

Comment: Is it possible for plants to grow from this light?

Comment: Plants can absolutely grow under this kind of light. They can even grow under less sun-like modern lamps. This is how criminals grow illegal marijuana indoors.